# Proof of an IF - THEN statement

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. IF $\exists m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n \in S, m \geq n$, THEN $\exists m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n \in S, m > n$

Now I know that we get to pick $m$ since its an existence statement, we can pick it as $m = n + 1$ or I can pick $m$ such that $m = \max(S)$, both of these methods guarantee that $m \geq n$. But if we use $m = \max(S)$ then it doesnt satisfy the property that $m > n$ which is required in the THEN statement. So I dont know whether I would say this statement is true or false. I think its false since I can use that max method to prove the THEN part false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true. Take $m^*\in\Bbb R$ such that, for each $n\in S$, $m^*\geqslant n$. Now, let $m=m^*+1$. Then, for each $n\in S$, $m>m^*\geqslant n$.

Comment: didn't you do the opposite? we were supposed to show that $m* \geq n$ and that implies that $m > m* \geq n$

Comment: Right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is confusingly written because there are two $m$'s which denote different numbers (according to logic). In fact, the second $m$ is chosen after the first $m$. A clearer way to write the formula: $$IF \exists m_1\in \mathbb{R}:\forall n\in S, m_1\ge n, THEN \exists m_2\in\mathbb{R}: \forall n_1\in S,  m_2>n_1.$$ The proof is easy: take $m_2=m_1+1$.